# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<>' to 'Model'.An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, listbox

I am new in MVC, I dont know much about MVC, so sometimes i cant got the error,
I am creating dual list box and move the items of listbox1 to listbox2, in first listbox fetch the data from database, so for that i have create the following..
 **Model.cs**

```
public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Model> AvailableModel { get; set; }

    public List<Model> RequestedModel { get; set; }

    public string[] AvailableSelected { get; set; }
    public string[] RequestedSelected { get; set; }
}
```

in controller to fetch the data from db i have create the following

```
[NonAction]
private Model getName()
{
    var name = (from m in db.Models
                select m);
    return name;
}

[NonAction]
public List<Model> getAllInstituteNameList()
{
    return getName();
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewModel model = new ViewModel { AvailableModel = getAllInstituteNameList(), RequestedModel = newList<Model>() };
    return View();
}
```

After runnig, it throws the following exception

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable' to
>   'DemoListBox.Models.Model'. An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)

on this line

```
var name = (from m in db.Models
    select m);
    return name;
```

Please help to solve it.....

**UPDATED**

After following your ans..
i again got this new exception on view

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

in this line

```
<%:Html.ListBoxFor(model =>model.AvailableSelected, newMultiSelectList(Model.AvailableModel, "Id", "Name", Model.AvailableSelected))%>
```

---

- edited

---

**View**

```
<h2>Index</h2>
<%using(Html.BeginForm()) {%>
<div>
<hr/>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>
                       Available
</th>

<th>

</th>

<th>
                       Requested
</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<%:Html.ListBoxFor(model =>model.AvailableSelected, newMultiSelectList(Model.AvailableModel, "Id", "Name", Model.AvailableSelected))%>
</td>

<td>
<inputid="add"name="add"type="submit"value=">>"/>
<br/>
<inputid="remove"name="remove"type="submit"value="<<"/>
</td>

<td>
<%:Html.ListBoxFor(model=>model.RequestedSelected,newMultiSelectList(Model.RequestedModel,"Id","Name",Model.RequestedSelected)) %>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br/>

<hr/>
</div>
<% }%>
```

Comment: Could you paste also the code of your `View`, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your getAllInstituteNameList expects collection of models (List).
Your getName returns single Model (what conflicts with above expected type).
Your getName tries to return Collection but expected result is a single Model. One more error.

```
[NonAction]
private List<Model>getName()
{
    var names = (from m in db.Models
                select m).ToList();
    return names;
}

[NonAction]
public List<Model> getAllInstituteNameList()
{
    return getNames();
}
```

**EDIT**

return model to the view

```
return View(model);
```

Comment: Que: after write this

private Model getName()
{
    var name = (db.Models).First();
    return name;
}

It again throws this exception Cannot implicitly convert type 'DemoListBox.Models.Model' to 'System.Collection.Generic.List'

Comment: @user3449277 please edit your question, not the answer

Comment: @user3449277 initialize all your properties in the model before your return model to view

Comment: @user3449277 you didn't return it to view. Check edit

Comment: Oh... I forgot it.. Thank you very much for ur help.. thanksssss

Answer (score 0):

As you see in your code returning type of method is Model and you return a Linq object that's why it through exception.